# Ошибка в Java Javax.swing

Tags: java

Работаю в программе Eclipse. Строчка **import javax.swing.***; подчеркивается красным. Выдается ошибка "**Разрешение для типа javax.swing.JComponent невозможно. В требуемых файлах Class. на него есть косвенная ссылка**"

Умные люди посоветовали выполнить следующие манипуляции:
*Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings  в правом окне находим Deprecated and restricted API раскрываем список и в нем ставим Ignore для Deprecated API и Ignore для Forbidden reference (access rules). После жмем Apply, потом ОК. И перезапускаем eclipse. После этого import java.swing.JOptionPane или import java.swing.* не должны подчеркиваться*

Но это не помогло :(
Подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Car {

int i, k;
String n1, n2;
public void Gogol(){
    n1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Введи число");
    n2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Введи число");

}
}
```

Comment: может быть какая-то проблема с подключением стандартной библиотеки, зайдите в Project -> Properties, Java Build Path, вкладка Libraries, там удалите все JRE System Library. Дальше добавьте библиотеку обратно, через Add Library... -> JRE System Library. Если не поможет, можно переустановить эклипс/яву